# Recursion to iteration - or optimization?

Tags: algorithm, actionscript-3, optimization, recursion, iteration

I've got an algorithm which searches for all possible paths between two nodes in graph, but I'm choosing path without repeating nodes and with my specified length of that path.
It is in ActionScript3 and I need to change my algorithm to iterative or to optimize it (if it's possible).
I have no idea how to do that and I'm not sure if changing to iterative will bring some better execution times of that function. Maybe it can't be optimized. I'm not sure.

Here is my function:
http://pastebin.com/nMN2kkpu

If someone could give some tips about how to solve that, that would be great.

Comment: Can you explain in very general terms what your algorithm is meant to achieve.  Is it supposed to find the shortest path between any given nodes, or is it supposed to just find all paths between all nodes?  If it's the former Djisktra's algorithm will do the trick, if it's the latter my guess is regardless this will be a fairly CPU costly operation.  I realize you did put something of an explanation  in your question it's just not entirely clear to me.

Comment: @shaunhusain Algorithm finds all paths between any given nodes, but my modifications only return path of my given length and every vertex of path can be used only once in my "generated" path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one thing, you could sort the edges by starting vertex. Then, iterating through a vertex' neighbours will be proportional to the number of neighbours of this vertex (while right now it's taking `O(M)`, where `M` is the edge count for the whole graph).

If you relax the condition of not repeating a vertex, I'm certain the problem can be solved in better time.

If, however, you need that, I'm afraid there's no simple change that would make your code way faster. I can't guarantee on this, though.

Also, if I am correct, the code snippet tests if the *edge* is used already, not if the *vertex* is used. Another thing I noticed is that you don't stop the recursion once you've found such a path. Since in most* graphs, such a path will exist for reasonable values of `length`, I'd say if you need only one such path, you might be wasting a lot of CPU time after one such path is found.

*Most - to be read 'maybe most (IMO)'.